# Review: git branch in statusline

Tags: vimscript, statusline, git

Note: this is an educational exercise. For those wanting a ready-made solution, use [vim-gitbranch](https://github.com/itchyny/vim-gitbranch).

I am learning vimscript, and the code below is part of my `.vimrc` used to display the current git branch in the statusline. I am aware that there are ready-made options out there, but this is more of an educational exercise. The purpose of this question is to solicit advice on improving the code.

The only arbitrary requirement of this exercise is that the git branch has to be obtained using a `system` call (instead of directly through the `.git` directory).

```
function! StatuslineGitBranch()
    if exists("g:git_branch")
        return g:git_branch
    else
        return ''
    endif
endfunction

function! GetGitBranch()
    let l:is_git_dir = system('echo -n $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree)')
    let g:git_branch = l:is_git_dir == 'true' ?
        \ system('bash -c "echo -n $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"') : ''
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter * call GetGitBranch()

set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%{StatuslineGitBranch()}
```

Reason for the existence of `g:git_branch`, and the slightly convoluted execution: so that statusline does not involve a `system` call ([reference](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3197)).

How can the above be improved? I'm new to this, so comments will be very helpful.

Comment: relevant meta: https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1482/10604

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You mentioned that the title somewhat misleading (I agree). Can you suggest a better title?

Comment: Comments will be helpful? How about a comment about comments? Or lack thereof. This is a short and straightforward bit of code so it's not a DEFCON 1 situation but it did pop a little red flag for me (experienced developer). If you share your code commenting it is critical but even if you never share at the very least you could be doing yourself a favor when you look back at your stuff in the future. (The older you get the truer that last part gets.)

Comment: Should you consider using a per-buffer variable (`b:git_branch`) instead of a global one? Technically, you could.have buffers opening files from different repos, with different branches checked out...

Answer (score 5):

The most general improvements I can give are to avoid the long `?:` and to make use of the `get` function on dictionaries.

For example, I would write

```
return get(g:, 'git_branch', '')
```

For the if, use a plain if

```
let l:is_git_dir = trim(system('git rev-parse --in-inside-work-tree'))
if l:is_git_dir is# 'true'
  let g:git_branch = trim(system('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'))
else
  let g:git_branch = ''
endif
```

(Note that I've upgraded your test to use `==#` for casing and the system call to be more portable: `system()` already uses `'shell'`, so no need to wrap that. Invoke git more or less directly. Also, `echo -n` is unreliable, and there is never a reason to `echo $(command)` when you could just `command`.)

Or, encode your data as data:

```
let l:is_git_dir = trim(system('git rev-parse --in-inside-work-tree'))
let g:git_branch = get(
        \ { 'true': trim(system('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD')) },
        \ l:is_git_dir,
        \ '')
```

Another note is that you're performing two system calls on every `BufEnter`; this may or may not be acceptable in terms of performance (measure!!!).

Finally, I'll add that your best bet is to dig into the ever-popular [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin and try to understand how its statusline function is constructed.

Comment: Thank you. I believe fugitive looks at the files in `.git` to find the branch name instead of using `system`. Other than fugitive, there is also [vim-gitbranch](https://github.com/itchyny/vim-gitbranch).

Answer (score 4):

0- +1 to D. Ben Knoble suggestions.

---

Regarding pure vim-scripting

1- Never define autocommands globally. Prefer to define them in their own group, and when filling the group, start by clearing it. This way, the related snippet of code can be re-executed, which you'll will want when you'll be working on your script

```
aug MyGitBranch
  au!
  au BufEnter * call s:GetGitBranch()
aug END
```

2- Avoid globally defined functions. Global functions may be defined/changed/removed by any other piece of code. Either define them as script local functions (with the `s:` prefix as I've done above), or as autoloaded functions if you need to export them (i.e. if you're defining a library plugin), or if they can be lazily loaded.

Regarding the specific case of statusline, I don't remember if we can use script-local functions.

3- Also, it's better to annotate functions with the `abort` keyword. In case an error is triggered (even if this is impossible on the current code, problems may be introduced on different flavours of Vim (the suggested `trim()` is quite recent for instance), or in later versions of your plugin.

`abort` ensure the function doesn't continue (this should be the default, but this is not how Vim used to work, and backward compatibility has been chosen here), and it'll also help decoding possible error messages.

4- I'd use `finddir()` to recursively find the upstream `.git/` directory instead of using `system()`. On user saturated machines, it can make the difference -- I've experienced such shared environments, and I've come to the conclusion it's always better to reduce the dependence of the system. Also, on Windows machines, calls to `system()` are really annoying and inefficient.

---

Otherwise, I not sure we can really avoid checking the current branch every time we switch the current buffer. If a `git checkout` is operated, we'll want to know the branch has changed. I don't know if there is a smart way to do it.

Comment: The reason for git rev-parse is that .git may not be in the project hierarchy. Worktrees and one of the git env variables (GIT_DIR maybe?) screw with this assumption.

Comment: `Regarding the specific case of statusline, I don't remember if we can use script-local functions.` A late comment: that's not directly possible, as `<SNR>` must be resolved first. But the following will work: `let &statusline .= '%{' . get(function("s:some_local_func"), "name") . '()}'` Although I don't see any reason to prefer this over an autoloaded function.